# creating relationships without IDs

Tags: sql, database

I have a table with a list of users (username, password). But this table was created without an ID and I cannot change it. How can I create a unique ID (integer if possible) to establish relationships to other tables?

UPDATE:

The list of user is not exactly a table in my database, it is just data obtained from a web service, so when the users log in into the system, I check if the credentials exist in the list of users, returning true or false. It works perfectly, but now I have to associate things to each user, like products. In a normal situation I just need to put the user ID in the products table, but here I don't have that ID.

To do that I was thinking in generate a hash based on the username of each user and use it like a unique ID, that way I can get an ID to use it in the table products.

is this a good solution?

Comment: Where is the table? SQL database? You need to provide a lot more details.

Comment: Why can't you change the table?  I assume you mean a MySQL table?  Can you add a new table?

Comment: Hi Carlos, Why can't you change the table? If you could run an alter table to add an id column, would be your best option. Is it mysql, sql server, sql lite?

Comment: 1. alter table, add int field. 2. populate int field. 3. alter table, change into to primary key autoincrement, 4. reset table's auto_increment value to be table's MAX(id)+1

Comment: Marc - you should probably post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Your username has a unique constraint, right? Otherwise that would be a very silly users table. So use it to make your relationships if you for whatever reason can't alter your table and add a normal id column (e.g. as Marc B suggested)

Comment: Hi Carlos, welcome to SO. As you may get from the many comments, some additional informations regarding your particular enviroment would be welcome and would help us to help you. Which database, why can't you alter it. Can you access it directly, or over a frontend, your knowhow-background, etc. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change the table for whatever reason, as you state in your question, I would think that at least `username` would be a unique value. Even though using a string as a primary key isn't ideal, it's perfectly doable, and there's nothing preventing you from using that for your relationships.

Granted, altering the table to add an `int` field would be the best way forward, but it's not actually necessary.

Comment: yea, i was thinking in use the username like an id too. maybe hashed, idk. thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any reason to bother hashing it.  I'd just use it as it exists already.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your question and situation is as follows:

1. You cannot change the fact that the table in question was created without independent `id'.
2. You have enough rights to add a field to this table as of now.
3. There is a way for you to get a time window where users' access to this table will be disabled.

If this is the case then you need to add this field and populate it with consecutive integers.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name INT FIRST;
```

Comment: This isn't defned as `UNIQUE`

Comment: i cant do that, thanks anyway.